# Precautions for difficulty faced on first day of gym

Tags: training, recovery, injury-prevention

This was quite bad day today in the gym and that too my first day. I vomited after doing just 20 sit ups in the final session of the day.

I'm newbie in fitness and don't know too much terms and i don't exercised previously. I am programmer by profession.

I did few lifts, presses, push ups, pull ups, stretching. Which affected nothing to me apart from little muscle pain due reason being first day in gym i believe. I had done gym 4years back for only 4months approx. Now i thought to start again.

Exercise followed:
In weight based: 3 sets with increasing weight by one slab. Like as below
1st set: 15kg 15times
2nd set: 30-40kg 12times
3rd set: same or more 10times

In other: 20times Like 20 Sit ups or stretching variations.

As i was exhausted after almost 50 min of exercises, i asked trainer to leave and he instructed me to do last two things, 20 sit ups and hand crunches (for fist strengthening) but after doing sit ups my body started weird feeling. I felt faints and un easy breathing. After few minutes of rest i felt like vomit and after vomiting all was well.

In vomit, it was water and few food particles from dinner yesterday.

My question are:
 1. Why it happened after sit ups only?
 2. What precaution i must take so if my trainer is going wrong i can prevent hurting myself?

Comment: It's probably nothing to worry about.  Vomiting from exercise is pretty common.  It generally happens when the body wants to use the blood in the stomach for other things than digestion, so the food is expelled.  You might want to try getting your blood sugar and electrolytes up prior to exercising by having a sports drink.  In any case, once you start getting used to working out, you should see the nausea subside.

Comment: Also important, make sure your stomach isn't too full, whether of food or water, particularly when doing stomach exercises (rapidly compressing the area) or aerobics (which typically involve all kinds of movement where the contents of your stomach will keep sloshing around).

Comment: Vomiting after/during very intense workouts is common, as @Doc suggests. Especially if you are new to exercise, pushing like that when you are already exhausted can cause them. As for why during situp, when you do situps you are compressing the muscles across the abdomen, which in turn can increase the pressure on your stomach. If it's already upset, that could easily trigger it.

Comment: Not related to your question, but ditch your workout and google "strong lifts 5x5". Add situps and other calisthenics if you like .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you were pushed just that little bit too hard, but like others have said, it shouldn't be anything to worry about.  Maybe you could get to the gym a few times without the trainer, to help increase your fitness. I'm sure after a few weeks of training this sickness will ease off.  For a beginner it's ideal if you can train 3 times a week. Even if a couple of sessions are just 20-30 minutes. It all helps.

Comment: Thanks for advice.. I will try to follow this 3days/week with 30 min initially then I would increase weight and durations gradually..

Comment: I have been doing workout 3 days a week and weight same as mentioned in question text. Also I take deep breath between the sets and wait for 30 sec to 1 min before next set. So far good going.

Comment: Great, pleased to hear its going well

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of precaution you have to take for the first day of gym.When you are going to join the gym after a long time then you have take care of some precaution.You have to try less weight dumbles. Go slowly when you walking in the trade mill.Do the less workout and exercise in the first day.If you decided to do the one hour workout then you go slow towards all your exercise your doing.Don't eat too much water and food before going to gym.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me today after doing pushups pullups nothing happened but after situps it was like as if i got drunk and wanted to vomit. I sat there for 10min and convinced my mind not to vomit and thought about all the worldwide bodybuilders and listened to the song and the feeling was gone, so I went and hit the weights.

If you have any problems like vomiting or fainting, pause for a few minutes and then start again don't stop because you dont backup from gym.